# output images from an array in the order starting with the time of day

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of images. When you click on the button, my images are scrolled in the same order in which they would change in real time (morning, afternoon, evening, night), starting from the one that corresponds to the current time of day. For example, if it is day, then when you click it should show evening. And if it's night, then the next morning must appear. My code, but it doesn't work

```
const images = ['assets/images/morning/01.jpg', 'assets/images/day/01.jpg', 'assets/images/evening/01.jpg', 'assets/images/night/01.jpg'];
  let i = 0;
function changeImage() { 
  let today = new Date(),
  hour = today.getHours();
  if (hour < 12) {
    // Morning
    i = 0;
  } 
  if (hour < 14) {
    i = 1
    document.body.style.color = 'black';
  } 
  if (hour < 18) {
    // evening
    i = 2
   } 
  if (hour < 0) {
    // Night
    i = 3  
  }
  let index = i;
  const imageSrc = images[index];
  viewBgImage(imageSrc);
  i++;
}
btnImage.addEventListener('click', changeImage)
```

Comment: I haven't run the code yet but it seems to me that `hour < 0` is not correct when you want to figure out if it's nights.

Comment: The code is not complete / situation is not reproducible. i.e. `viewBgImage` and `btnImage` are not defined in this code. But maybe as a bit of general advice, you can consider that global state tracking with a generic variable name `let i` is not a good idea. Alternatively, you can track the state as an attribute of a container which has `<img>` tag. In my opinion, `viewBgImage` is, in fact, the function that changes the image and `changeImage` is a refresh procedure.

Answer (score 0):

1. if hour is **10**, first three conditions will be true, so you will end up changing "i" variable several times, use **else if** instead !
2. hour < 0 is not valid condition